# Which technique is used to show the grown up Renesmee?

Tags: film-techniques, breaking-dawn-2, the-twilight-saga

In the end of [The Twilight Saga: Breaking Dawn – Part 2](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Twilight_Saga%3a_Breaking_Dawn_%E2%80%93_Part_2) Alice's vision shows the  grown up Renesmee. So how this scene got achieved? How they managed to show a young Renesmee to a mature Renesmee?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On the [IMDB page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1673434/combined), there are a number of actresses listed as playing Renesmee at various points in her growth including one credit for "Christie Burke   ...    Renesmee (Young Woman)".

So it seems unlikely that any special effects were used.

Comment: Didn't know about that. The mature renesmee looks identical to the little renesmee, so i get confused . But anyways this seems to be the right answer.

Comment: When watching the movie, it appears to me there is some CGI used to impose the older face onto a younger body; no proof here, though, just conjecture on my part. I thought the effect was actually very poorly done. In today's age of movie making, if you can see the effect (or tell the effect), the effects people aren't doing a very good job. JMHO, though.